# modal code is not working when appended through js in materialize

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, materialize

I am trying to open a modal with a click on the icon.This icon is generated by js in table with respective data but it doesn't work

but when I copy-paste same code in blade.php file it works fine.

I am attaching screenshots as well.
hope could get an answer.

note: using laravel

```js
function actionFormatter(value, row, index) {
         if (row.status == '1') {


             return [
                 
                 '<a class="editGreenColor tooltipped modal-trigger"   data-tooltip="Edit" href="#modal5">',
                 '<i title="Edit" class="mdi-content-create small fontSzie1pt5rm"></i>',
                 '</a> ',
                 
                 
             ].join('');
         }
     }
```

```html
<table data-toolbar="#toolbar" class="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-table" data-unique-id="id"  
data-toggle="table" data-url="{{url('/branches/')}}/{{ $prantId }}/get" style="font-size: 14px" data-filter-control="true" data-row-style="rowStyle" 
id="branchTable" data-pagination="true">
<thead>
  <tr>
   <th data-field="id" data-align="center" data-width="5%" data-sortable="true">ID</th>
   
   <th id="name" data-field="name" data-width="25%" data-sortable="true" data-formatter="allBranchViewFormatter">Name</th>

   <th data-field="id" data-formatter="actionFormatter" >Actions</th>
 </tr>
</thead>
</table>










<div id="modal5" class="modal bottom-sheet">

// some codes

</div>
```

[screenshot1](http://fluidux.in/test/q1.png)

[screenshot2](http://fluidux.in/test/q2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding an onClick function, thanks for help @cris

```js
function openEdit() {

  $(".modal").openModal()
}
```

```html
<a class="editGreenColor tooltipped modal-trigger" data-tooltip="Edit" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openEdit()">
  <i title="Edit" class="mdi-content-create small fontSzie1pt5rm"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the modal yourself. Check http://materializecss.com/modals.html#initialization

Comment: I tried it, doesn't work. is it because it is appending data?

Comment: Did you initialize the modal **after** adding the anchor?

Comment: i didn't get you, could u explain a bit? i am new to programming so.

Comment: You are adding the anchor programmatically, so you should initialize the modal after calling the `actionFormatter` function for the last time

Comment: @cris solved the question, I've commented my answer. thank you for help.
if you have a better solution, please comment it with an example :)